# How to draw linear regression between two sliders?

Tags: r, shiny, linear-regression

```
FitWeibull <- function(data, xinf, xsup){
sub.data <- data[(data$X >= log(xinf) & data$X <= log(xsup),]
my.lm <- lm(Y~X, data = sub.data)
return(my.lm)
}
```

Xinf and xsup is the limit of my linear regression, on shiny people will moove a slider ( and choose a range), the question is how can i identify the two slider by xinf and xsup ?

Thank you.

Comment: any idea for the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

in ui.R

```
sliderInput(inputId=XValues, label="This slider determines Xinf and Xsup or 
    whatever", min=0, max=1000, value=c(0,1000))
```

And in your server.R:

```
FitWeibull <- function(data, xinf, xsup){
sub.data <- data[(data$X >= log(input$XValues[1]) & data$X <= log(input$XValues[2]),]
my.lm <- lm(Y~X, data = sub.data)
return(my.lm)
}
```

I just put in 0 and 1000 as example values for min and max, you should put in /calculate something reasonable. This will make a slider that returns two values, you can access them using XValues[1] and XValues[2]

Comment: This is exectly what i want! just one thing, in this case xinf and xsup are needful ?

Comment: Instead of having two values, you can just have the slider produce a vector of length 2. So, I don't think you need them.